# Unable to get the correct star position in rating bar

Tags: android, kotlin, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore, ratingbar

In this shopping app, I try to set/get ratings for the product using Firebase firestore db, The problem is happening when I try to set a product rating, firstly I have the following fields in this path **>>> /PRODUCTS/PRODUCT_ID_XYZ/**

1_star (number)
2_star (number)
3_star (number)
4_star (number)
5_star (number)

average_rating (String)
total_ratings (String)

and this is the **rating layout**, that contains the basic rating bar made by me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:elevation="3dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ratings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
        android:text="Ratings"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_20ssp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/productRatingContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ratings">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/averageRatingTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
            android:text="4.5"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_36ssp"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/averageRatingStar"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/star"
            app:tint="@color/black">

        </ImageView>


    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondTotalRatingsTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="27 ratings"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/productRatingContainer" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ratingProgressBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/productRatingContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/productRatingContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/secondTotalRatingsTV">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="80"
            android:progressTint="#00AC06" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="60"
            android:progressTint="#00AC06" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="40"
            android:progressTint="#E4CD00" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="30"
            android:progressTint="#E4CD00" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar5"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="10"
            android:progressTint="#ff0000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ratingProgressBarContainer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ratingProgressBarContainer"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ratingProgressBarContainer">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ratingMiniViewTV1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ratingMiniStar1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/star"
                app:tint="@color/black">

            </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productRatingMiniViewTV2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ratingMiniStar2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/star"
                app:tint="@color/black">

            </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productRatingMiniViewTV3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/star"
                app:tint="@color/black">

            </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productRatingMiniViewTV4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ratingMiniStar4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:src="@drawable/star"
                app:tint="@color/black">

            </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/productRatingMiniViewTV5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp"
                android:textStyle="bold">

            </TextView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ratingMiniStar5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/star"
                app:tint="@color/black">

            </ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ratingNumbersContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ratingProgressBarContainer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ratingProgressBarContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ratingProgressBarContainer">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="9"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#727272"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="5"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#727272"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="7"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#727272"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="10"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#727272"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="2"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#727272"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#707070"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ratingNumbersContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ratingNumbersContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ratingNumbersContainer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalRatingsFigure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="27"
        android:textColor="#727272"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/ratingNumbersContainer"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/ratingNumbersContainer"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ratingNumbersContainer" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/arial"
        android:text="your ratings"
        android:textColor="#727272"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout6" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rateNowContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/starIV01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star"
            app:tint="@color/mediumGray" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/starIV02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star"
            app:tint="@color/mediumGray" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/starIV03"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star"
            app:tint="@color/mediumGray" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/starIV04"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star"
            app:tint="@color/mediumGray" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/starIV05"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/star"
            app:tint="@color/mediumGray" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the setting rate method in my repo

```
interface ProductDetailsRepo {

    suspend fun setRating(
        productId: String,
        starPosition: Long,
        whatStar:Long,
        averageRating:Long,
        totalRatings:Long,
        myRatingIds: ArrayList<String>,
        myRating: ArrayList<Long>
    ) :Flow<Resource<Boolean>>

}
```

and the implementation ProductDetailsRepoImpl

```
class ProductDetailsRepoImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val firestore: FirebaseFirestore,
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
) : ProductDetailsRepo {

    override suspend fun setRating(
        productId: String,
        starPosition: Long,
        whatStar: Long,
        averageRating: Long,
        totalRatings: Long,
        myRatingIds: ArrayList<String>,
        myRating: ArrayList<Long>
    ): Flow<Resource<Boolean>> {

        val result = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Ideal())

        result.value = Resource.Loading()

        val productRating: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()

        productRating[(starPosition + 1).toString() + "_star"] = whatStar

        productRating["average_rating"] = averageRating
        productRating["total_ratings"] = totalRatings

        firestore.collection("PRODUCTS")
            .document(productId)
            .update(productRating)
            .addOnSuccessListener {

                val rating: HashMap<String, Any> = HashMap()

                rating["list_size"] = myRatingIds.size.toLong() + 1
                rating["product_id_" + myRating.size] = productId
                rating["rating_" + myRatingIds.size] = starPosition.toLong() + 1

                firestore.collection(
                    "USERS"
                ).document(firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid!!)
                    .collection("USER_DATA")
                    .document("MY_RATINGS")
                    .update(rating).addOnSuccessListener {
                        result.value = Resource.Success(true)
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())
                    }

            }.addOnFailureListener {
                result.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())

            }

        return result
    }
}
```

viewModel layer

```
@HiltViewModel
class ProductDetailsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val setRatingUseCase: SetRatingUseCase ) :
    ViewModel() {
private var _setRatingState = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Boolean>>(Resource.Ideal())
val setRatingState: Flow<Resource<Boolean>> get() = _setRatingState

    fun setRatings(
        productId: String,
        starPosition: Long,
        whatStar: Long,
        averageRating: Long,
        totalRatings: Long,
        myRatingIds: ArrayList<String>,
        myRating: ArrayList<Long>
    ) {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            setRatingUseCase(
                productId,
                starPosition,
                whatStar,
                averageRating,
                totalRatings,
                myRatingIds,
                myRating
            ).collect {
                _setRatingState.emit(it)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and this the UI/Fragment part and I think the problem happens here, the expected scenario is it should loop on `rateNowContainer.childCount` which is 5 stars and set the click listener for each star according to **starPosition** , so when the user clicks on the first star the rating UI elements (like progressbar and textview) updated to 1 star, when user click on 2 stars it's updated to two stars and so on..., but the problem is when I click on any star it's updated as 5 star, I tried to log the starPosition before I click on any star and I see that the for working immediately and the count start from position 4 which is (5 star) but I didn't know how to fix it

```
       //========= Rating layout
        for (i in 1 until  binding.ratingsLayout.rateNowContainer.childCount) {

            Log.d(TAG, "index: $i")


            starPosition = i.toLong()

            Log.d(TAG, "starPosition: $starPosition")

            binding.ratingsLayout.rateNowContainer.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener { view ->

                if (signOutViewModel.firebaseAuth.currentUser == null) {
                    Constants.signInSignUpDialog(
                        requireContext(),
                        R.id.productDetailsFragment,
                        layoutInflater,
                        requireView()
                    )
                } else {
                    setRating(i.toLong())

                    if (myRatingsIds.contains(productId)) {

                    } else {

                        Log.d(TAG, "starPosition: $starPosition")

                        productDetailsViewModel.setRatings(
                            productId, starPosition,
                            whatStar = starPosition +1,
                            averageRating = calculateAverageRating(starPosition + 1),
                            totalRatings = documentSnapshot["total_ratings"] as Long + 1,
                            myRatingsIds,
                            myRatings

                        )
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
                productDetailsViewModel.setRatingState.collect{ response->
                    if(response is Resource.Success){

                        myRatingsIds.add(productId)
                        myRatings.add(starPosition+1)

                        val ratingTV = binding.ratingsLayout
                            .ratingNumbersContainer.getChildAt( (5 - starPosition - 1).toInt()) as TextView

                        ratingTV.text = (ratingTV.text.toString().toInt() + 1).toString()


                        binding.productImageViewPager.productTotalRatingMiniViewTV.text =
                            "(" + documentSnapshot["total_ratings"] as Long + 1 + ") Ratings"

                        binding.ratingsLayout.secondTotalRatingsTV.text =
                            (documentSnapshot["total_ratings"] as Long + 1).toString() + " ratings"


                        binding.ratingsLayout.totalRatingsFigure.text =
                            (documentSnapshot["total_ratings"] as Long + 1).toString()

                        binding.ratingsLayout.averageRatingTV.text = calculateAverageRating(starPosition + 1)
                            .toString()

                        binding.productImageViewPager.averageRatingMiniViewTV.text =
                            calculateAverageRating(
                                starPosition + 1
                            ).toString()

                        for (x in 0..4) {
                            val ratingFigures =
                                binding.ratingsLayout.ratingNumbersContainer.getChildAt(x) as TextView
                            val progressBar =
                                binding.ratingsLayout.ratingProgressBarContainer.getChildAt(x) as ProgressBar
                            val maxProgress =
                                Integer.valueOf((documentSnapshot["total_ratings"] as Long + 1).toString())
                            //
                            progressBar.max = maxProgress
                            progressBar.progress = ratingFigures.text.toString()
                                .toInt()
                        }



                            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Thanks for rating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }else if(response is Resource.Error){
                        setRating(initialRating)
                        Log.e(TAG, "setRatingState: ${response.message.toString()}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

this image is for the rating layout

[image]

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **700** (seven hundred) lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way, you increase your chances of being helped. Please take a moment and read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using a for loop in Kotlin to iterate through the children of a view and set their click listeners. You are wondering why the for loop starts immediately and the star position is changed immediately, and how to prevent this.

According to the Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html), a for loop iterates through anything that provides an iterator, such as a range, an array, a string, or a collection. In your case, you are using the until keyword to create a range from 1 until the child count of the view. This means that the loop will start from 1 and end at the child count minus one.

The loop will execute the body for each value in the range, which means that it will set the click listener for each child view and assign the star position to the current index. This happens when the loop is executed, not when the user clicks on the view.

If you want to prevent this, you need to move the logic that depends on the user’s click inside the click listener, and also you can use the indexOfChild method of the view group to get the index of a specific child view. For example, you can do something like this: For example, you can do something like this:

```
for (i in 1 until binding.ratingsLayout.rateNowContainer.childCount) {

            Log.d(TAG, "index: $i")

            binding.ratingsLayout.rateNowContainer.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener { view ->

 // get the star position of the view's
starPosition = binding.ratingsLayout.rateNowContainer.indexOfChild(view).toLong()


                Log.d(TAG, "starPosition: $starPosition")

                if (signOutViewModel.firebaseAuth.currentUser == null) {
                    Constants.signInSignUpDialog(
                        requireContext(),
                        R.id.productDetailsFragment,
                        layoutInflater,
                        requireView()
                    )
                } else {
                    setRating(starPosition,false)

                    if (myRatingsIds.contains(productId)) {

                    } else {

                        Log.d(TAG, "starPosition: $starPosition")

                        productDetailsViewModel.setRatings(
                            productId, starPosition,
                            whatStar = starPosition +1,
                            averageRating = calculateAverageRating(starPosition + 1),
                            totalRatings = documentSnapshot["total_ratings"] as Long + 1,
                            myRatingsIds,
                            myRatings

                        )
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```